# PowerShell. Create 2 Storage Space Pools with right disks

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that will Create 2 Storage Spaces Pools with 4 disks each. However, due to caching requirements I need to use disks with LUN0-3 for pool1 and disks with LUN4-7 for pool2. I use the following script to create 2 pools, but each time I run it it creates pools from different disks (see screenshots):

```
$disks = Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true | select -first ((Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true).count/2)
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName "DataPool" -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage*" -PhysicalDisks $disks | New-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "DataDisk" -UseMaximumSize -NumberOfColumns $disks.Count -ResiliencySettingName "Simple" -ProvisioningType Fixed | Initialize-Disk -Confirm:$False -PassThru | New-Partition -DriveLetter S –UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "SQLDATA" -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -Confirm:$false            

$disks2 = Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName "LogsPool" -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage*" -PhysicalDisks $disks2 | New-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "LogsDisk" -UseMaximumSize -NumberOfColumns $disks.Count -ResiliencySettingName "Simple" -ProvisioningType Fixed | Initialize-Disk -Confirm:$False -PassThru | New-Partition -DriveLetter L –UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "SQLLOGS" -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -Confirm:$false
```

How can I make it work?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pool1 must have disks with LUN0, LUN1, LUN2, LUN3. But on deploymen1, as per screenshot 2 it has LUN4, LUN3, LUN6, LUN2. On deployment2 it has LUN 3, LUN 1, LUN 2, LUN 5. Making it impossible to set proper caching. I could do nested deployment work around, but I was looking for PowerShell code, so it's more ... effective?

Comment: well, i don't have ability to replicate your environment, but why don't you filter them?

Comment: I don't know if I can. All values are exactly the same. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq7n9.png
At least on SQL Server 2016, on SQL Server 2014 values might be different (but I need 2016 though).

Comment: can you show output of `Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true | gm`

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/NLvPwjTi

Comment: can you try several of those, like: `(get-physicaldisk -canpool $true).EnclosureNumber` or `.ObjectId` or `.SlotNumber`, some of those might help?

Comment: `.ObjectID` returned this http://pastebin.com/pE8Bp0cd
others came up empty

Comment: `.PhysicalLocation` did it https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuqzr.png thanks, a lot! But, I still don't know how to sort it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you sort them by deviceId to get the correct disks?

```
$disks = Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true | Sort-Object deviceid | select -first ((Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true).count/2)
```

Or in some other way make use of the deviceId to explicitly specify disks 0-3 and 4-7

Answer (score 3):

```
$disks = (get-physicaldisk -canpool $true).PhysicalLocation | sort
```

Try this to sort those

Comment: Hey, I'm afraid that didn't work :(
http://pastebin.com/4aNDQa6N
My guess is that expected value was something like this:
`Msft Virtual Disk              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 1023 GB` (with `Get-PhysicalDisk`) but the actual value was this:
`Integrated : Adapter 3 : Port 0 : Target 0 : LUN 2` (with `(get-physicaldisk -canpool $true).PhysicalLocation | sort`)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but: I either use the drive serialnumber OR unique ID to make sure I get the right drives.

Here an real world example for using the serialnumber. This is from my log creating a parity space, I always log how I create the storage space. I am omitting the drives I am not using for storage space here:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | ft friendlyname,canpool,cannotpoolreason,size,uniqueid,SerialNumber,Usage

friendlyname            canpool CannotPoolReason               size uniqueid         SerialNumber    Usage
------------            ------- ----------------               ---- --------         ------------    -----
ST33000651AS               True                       3000592982016 5000C5002DFAB4EE 9XK0EC9S        Auto-Select
WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0       True                       3000592982016 50014E6EADFAE1EF WD-WMC1T3418930 Auto-Select
WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0       True                       3000592982016 50014E6E58A5BD05 WD-WMC1T3536082 Auto-Select

New-StoragePool -FriendlyName Pool-F -StorageSubSystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage*" -LogicalSectorSizeDefault 4096 -PhysicalDisks (Get-PhysicalDisk | ?{"9XK0EC9S;WD-WMC1T3418930;WD-WMC1T3536082".Contains($_.SerialNumber)})
    
FriendlyName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly    Size AllocatedSize
------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------    ---- -------------
Pool-F       OK                Healthy      False        False      8.19 TB        768 MB
```

I could have used Unique ID:

```
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName Pool-F -StorageSubSystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage*" -LogicalSectorSizeDefault 4096 -PhysicalDisks (Get-PhysicalDisk | ?{"5000C5002DFAB4EE;50014E6EADFAE1EF;50014E6E58A5BD05".Contains($_.uniqueid)})
```

In your case you can use PhysicalLocation or ObjectID as selector as well... Here the list how it looks right now with physical location:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | ft friendlyname,canpool,cannotpoolreason,size,uniqueid,SerialNumber,PhysicalLocation,Usage

friendlyname            canpool CannotPoolReason               size uniqueid         SerialNumber    PhysicalLocation                                                Usage
------------            ------- ----------------               ---- --------         ------------    ----------------                                                -----
WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0      False In a Pool             3000592982016 50014E6EADFAE1EF WD-WMC1T3418930 PCI Slot 1 : Bus 4 : Device 0 : Function 0 : Adapter 1 : Port 1 Auto-Select
WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0      False In a Pool             3000592982016 50014E6E58A5BD05 WD-WMC1T3536082 Integrated : Bus 1 : Device 0 : Function 1 : Adapter 0 : Port 3 Auto-Select
ST33000651AS              False In a Pool             3000592982016 5000C5002DFAB4EE 9XK0EC9S        Integrated : Bus 1 : Device 0 : Function 1 : Adapter 0 : Port 4 Auto-Select
```